# Ruby Upload via SFTP Throws bignum error

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver, acceptance-testing

I have an automated ruby script that runs and completes tasks to my online application.  After each task, my Selenium/Watir webdriver takes a full page screenshot and stores it on my local disk.  After all tasks are completed I then upload all of the files to an sftp server; however, the upload process will randomly throw an error my way and kill the current upload process.

```
W, [2016-10-14T13:37:11.247877 #772]  WARN -- : Could not send file(s) to sftp server
W, [2016-10-14T13:37:11.248442 #772]  WARN -- : bignum too big to convert into `long'
```

The first warning being a custom warning message while the second one is the error message returned from the rescue operation.

```
def send_to_sftp(db, what)
#Create SSH connection to SFTP server
begin
    Net::SFTP.start(SFTP_HOST, SFTP_USERNAME, :password => SFTP_PASSWORD) do |sftp|
        # Create snapshot directory on server
        # Create the directories
        datastore_dir = SFTP_QASYNC_PATH + db
        snapshot_dir = datastore_dir + what

        begin
            sftp.mkdir!(SFTP_QASYNC_PATH + db, :permissions => 0500)
        rescue => e
            log_error('Could not create ' + datastore_dir + '. Directory already exists', e)
        end

        sftp.mkdir!(snapshot_dir, :permissions => 0500)

        # Find local files
        local_snapshots = LOGS_LOCATION + db + what

        # Upload local files to the remote host
        sftp.upload(local_snapshots, snapshot_dir)

        # Shut down sftp session
        sftp.session.shutdown!
    end
rescue => e
    log_error('Could not send file(s) to sftp server', e)
end
end
```

Backtrace from the rescue returned this.  Not really sure what any of it means or leads to.

```
["C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:194:in `malloc'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:194:in `malloc_ptr'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:257:in `get_token_information'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:230:in `get_current_user'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:207:in `get_security_attributes_for_user'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:349:in `send_query'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:326:in `send'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:148:in `send_packet'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:165:in `send_and_wait'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:91:in `identities'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:104:in `each_identity'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-3.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:236:in `start'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:31:in `start'",
"C:/Projects/insight/AcceptanceTests/CucumberRegression/features/support/system.rb:45:in `send_to_sftp'",
"C:/Projects/insight/AcceptanceTests/CucumberRegression/features/support/scorecards.rb:110:in `cycle_scorecards'",
"C:/Projects/insight/AcceptanceTests/CucumberRegression/features/step_definitions/Thens.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'",
"C:/Projects/insight/AcceptanceTests/CucumberRegression/features/step_definitions/Thens.rb:85:in `each'",
"C:/Projects/insight/AcceptanceTests/CucumberRegression/features/step_definitions/Thens.rb:85:in `block in <top (required)>'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:25:in `instance_exec'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:25:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:42:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:13:in `cucumber_instance_exec'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_step_definition.rb:102:in `invoke'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:27:in `invoke'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:20:in `block in activate'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/action.rb:23:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/step.rb:31:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:104:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:51:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:26:in `test_step'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/step.rb:16:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `each'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:22:in `block in test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:16:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:104:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:51:in `execute'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:33:in `around_hook'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/around_hook.rb:11:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in compose_around_hooks'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:107:in `compose_around_hooks'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:24:in `block in describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:18:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_around_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_before_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_step_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/activate_steps.rb:11:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:23:in `describe_to'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:17:in `block in done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `each'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:61:in `done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:23:in `done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:35:in `done'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.5.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:18:in `compile'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:67:in `run!'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/cucumber:22:in `load'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/cucumber:22:in `<top (required)>'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in `debug_load'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in `debug_program'",
"C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in `<top (required)>'",
"-e:1:in `load'",
"-e:1:in `<main>'"]
```

Comment: maybe you should log the entire backtrace e.g `e.backtrace` in your `rescue` block that will give you some insight

Comment: I added the backtrace.  To a beginner it's not really telling me much.

Comment: looks like the file is bigger than whatever the size of Long is

Comment: from here it's trying to allocation memory https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb#L194 and the ruby function that does the memory allocation does `s = NUM2LONG(size);` which blows up because size is too big to cast to long I suppose

Comment: So were saying that the file size of the image I am trying to upload is too large or the filename is too long??